# Stable splitting of products

Tags: homotopy-theory

This question concerns the well-known homotopy equivalence
$$
\Sigma (X\times Y) \simeq \Sigma (X \vee \  Y) \vee \Sigma (X\wedge Y)
$$
(I'm happy to use only CW complexes).  I can see that 
there is a partition
$$
\Sigma (X\times Y) = \Sigma (X\vee Y) \cup C^\circ ( X\wedge Y)
$$
on the point-set level (here $C^\circ A$ denotes the open cone on the space $A$).  This is consistent with (but does not imply that) 
$$
\Sigma (X\times Y)\quad
\mbox{is homeomorphic to}\quad
\Sigma (X\vee Y)\cup_\alpha C( X\wedge Y),
$$
the mapping cone of some map $X\wedge Y \to \Sigma (X\vee Y)$
for some map $\alpha: X\wedge Y$ (which is necessarily nullhomotopic).

My question is: Is there such a map $\alpha$?   Is it natural?